# KVO versus NSUndoManager

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing

I have a property on my document class called `passDescription`, of type `NSMutableDictionary`. When I call `setPassDescription:`, the current value of the property is archived into an `NSData` instance using `NSJSONSerialization`. The property’s backing ivar, `passDescription`, is updated, and then an undo action is registered. The selector invoked by the action reconstitutes the `NSData` given to it and calls `setPassDescription:`.

Now, here’s the joker: `passDescription` is being observed using Key-Value Observing. Considerable experimentation and examination in Xcode’s debugger reveals that the old value and the new value are **identical**. (I know that this isn’t a pointer-aliasing issue, as that’s why I’m using an `NSData` instance. The `NSData` is created before I record the new value, making it independent of what it was created from.) Thus, when I press Command-Z to undo, nothing happens as the value that has just been restored is no different from the value that has been overwritten by the undo.

The only thing I can think of that may be causing this is that KVO is setting the `passDescription` ivar for me, before `setPassDescription:` gets called. Why would this be, and how could I prevent KVO from doing that? (I have confirmed that the setter isn’t being called twice. If it was, I would see double output in the debugger console.)

Here is the source for `setPassDescription:`.

```
- (void)setPassDescription:(NSDictionary *)param
{
    NSLog(@"passDescription (before) = \n%@", passDescription);

    NSError *error;
    NSData *archivedOldValue = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:passDescription options:0 error:&error];
    NSAssert(archivedOldValue != nil, @"Could not archive old pass description: %@", error);

    NSData *blob = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:param options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    if (blob == nil) @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"PBJSONException" reason:@"Could not serialize pass.json" userInfo:@{ @"error": error }];

    [self.fileBrowserRoot fileWrapperWithName:@"pass.json"].fileContents = blob;

    [passDescriptionLock lock];
    [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setPassDescriptionFromData:archivedOldValue];
    passDescription = param;
    [passDescriptionLock unlock];

    NSLog(@"passDescription (after) = \n%@", passDescription);

    // After the pass description has been set, refresh the list of build issues.
    [self recheckForIssues];
}
```

Comment: Normally it shouldn't set the value for you. Thats what a setter is for. Could you post some code (and perhaps a bit more context)? Are you sure another call to setPassDescription: is not happening *afterwards* with the same value? That could perhaps create an extra undo operation with identical data, and it would seem as if the old data is the same..

Comment: @user2311023 – updated info